# I can't log in to Ubuntu with password

Tags: ubuntu, login, console

I can't log in through the password via graphical login. I type the password and press Enter.  I then get the message "Failed to login with password". When I switch to terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) I can't type there. Just black screen with flashing cursor.

Comment: Don't you also enter your username? Is "Failed to login with password" the actual error message that you get?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean that you cannot log in ***at all?***  If so, say that.  If you can log in, say *how.*       Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.